# Searching for null slot in array

Tags: java, arrays, parseint

I am trying to search for the first null slot in the array. Can you `parseInt()` quotes to do this, or would I use "`stobar[b] == null`"?

```
int[] stobar = new int[100];
for(int b = 0; b < stobar.length; b++)
{
    if(stobar[b] == Integer.parseInt(""))
    {
        stobar[b] = row;
        stobar[b+1] = col;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this example cannot possibly self-contained: If you initialize the entire array on one line and iterator over it on the next one, you would always have the default value in each cell. The default value for Integer is 'null' while default value for int is '0'.

Answer (score 8):

Neither of those are going to work the way you want, since you have a primative array, which can only hold integers. If you want a distinct null value, you need to make it an `Integer[]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Integer[] stobar = new Integer[100];
...

for(int b=0; b<stobar.length; b++ )
{
    if(stobar[b]==null)
    {
      stobar[b] = row;
      stobar[b+1] = col;
      break;
    }
}
```

Are you sure that you want to use a static array? Maybe an ArrayList is more suitable for you.

I don't know what are you trying but take a look at the following implementation

```
public class Point
{
  private int row;
  private int col;

  public Point(int row, int col)
  {
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

    ...
    Point p = new Point(5,8);
    points.add(p);
    ...
  }

}
```